# Keep li selected after filter search angular js

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have three list items in a ul. There are three first names: Roy, Sam, David. I could toggle each li on click just fine. However, when I do a search and come back, the selected items are not highlighted anymore. Any suggestion on how I could keep them selected. Here is the my js fiddle:

```js
var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

app.controller("con",function($scope){
  $scope.firstNames = ['Sam', 'David', 'Roy'];

});

app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
<ul ng-repeat="firstName in firstNames | filter:searchText">
<li toggle-class="active">{{firstName}}</li>

</ul>
  
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baa2G/126/

Thanks.

Comment: Are the selections supposed to behave as radio buttons, or can you have multiple selected at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-class` instead. Always think about how to use your data model first...and let it control the view

```
<li ng-class="{active: selected[firstName]}" 
    ng-click="toggleSelected(firstName)">{{firstName}}</li>
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.selected = selected = {};
   $scope.toggleSelected = function(name){  
      selected[name] = !selected[name];
   }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/baa2G/127/)**

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks. I am new to angular js. One question, what does this line do ( $scope.selected = selected = {};) in simple english? I know you declare a model called selected, what is the second selected for?

Comment: I'm lazy and hate writing `$scope` all the time inside functions.... both variables reference same object...but view only recognizes properties of `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

Edited, because I didn't read your question properly!

Use Angular to store your selections in your controller.

I've modified your `firstNames` to `users` and changed each entry to an object.

```
$scope.users = [
    {name: 'Sam', isSelected, false},
    {name: 'David', isSelected, false}, 
    {name: 'Roy', isSelected, false}
];
$scope.toggleSelection(user){
    user.isSelected = !user.isSelected;
}
<ul ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText">
<li ng-click="toggleSelection(user)" ng-class="{'active': user. isSelected}">{{user.name}}</li>
```